# Is it a good practice to put html code with plain text as a value of an attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it considered a **good** or a **bad** **practice** to put text and html code as a value of an attribute, here is an example :

```
<script>
  var name = '<h3>name</h3>Here goes a description about the name   attribute';
  var elem = document.getElementById('monElem');
  elem.innerHTML = name;
</script>
```

knowing the fact that the text between html tags is a static text not a dynamic one.
If it is a bad practice then is the solution to use a **template engine** ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: For example i have a text when a user hover over it i display another text(html + plain text ) in another part of the same web page

Comment: You could include that in the initial HTML and then use CSS to hide/display it when needed. Is there any reason not to do so?

Comment: To many copies of IE out there for template strings, and very little mobile support. Is it bad practice? Depends on the project. Edit: oh I read template string, not templates.. My bad sorry.

Comment: Yes using a css selectors is one of the options, but it's kind of i'm looking for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using this code to generate **a lot** of DOM content, i.e. execute it a few hundred or thousand times, you'll be good.

Just for completeness I'd like to mention that there's a few other ways of generating HTML content from Javascript:

1. [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
2. [document.createDocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)
3. [`<template>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template)

The performance of these three is generally higher than using `innerHTML`, but the differences between the three are currently pretty inconsistent between browsers and browser versions.

Also, `<template>` isn't fully supported in all browsers yet and won't be supported in older browsers.

Comment: `<template>` isn't supported everywhere, but `<script type='text/html'>` pretty much is.  Works beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to show/hide this static `HTML` on demand, then it might be even better not to dynamically add and remove it from your `HTML` document, but to show/hide it via `CSS`:

```
<body>
    <div id="hoverMe" onmouseout="showHelp(0)" onmousemove="showHelp(1)">
        Hover me to learn about "name"
    </div>
    <div id="monElem" style="display:none">
        <h3>name</h3>
        Here goes a description about the name   attribute
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    var elem = document.getElementById('monElem');
    function showHelp(show) {
        elem.style.display = show ? '' : 'none';
    }
</script>
```

This will also have better performance than adding the elements to the DOM at the moment of need.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on styleguide in your team, but in most cases it's a bad practice.

The better solution is when you'll create new element throught javascript:

```
var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
var text = document.createTextNode("Any name … .");
h3.appendChild(text);

var elem = document.getElementById('monElem');    
elem.insertBefore(h3, elem.firstChild);
```

Why is it better? Just because it's faster, more conviniet and predictable.

Read more about document methods [on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_document.asp).

Comment: I believe the contrary 
``var h3 = '<h3>some text</h3';
elem.innerHTML = h3;`` 
is better then creating a DOM element then append it to the elem element

Comment: For rapidity and time saving   purposes